# Django project on PythonAnywhere works but no functionality, although it does locally

Tags: python, django, deployment, pythonanywhere

I've just deployed my first site on PythonAnywhere, which is a Craigslist clone for which the search functionality works as expected locally but when deployed I can only access the homepage and then I get two different errors depending on the browser I try it on. Feel free to try it yourselves at http://matipule.eu.pythonanywhere.com/

**This is Safari**
https://dpaste.com/3ZAJFC4PM

**This is Chrome**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7caWG.jpg

Chrome claims having an issue with the CSRF but I've included the token in the form as you can see below and then again, it actually works locally so I'm clueless.

This is the code where the token is in.

```
<form action="{% url 'new_search' %}" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search">
     <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
         <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
     </button>
 </form>
```

**UPDATE**
What made it work was what the accepted answer suggested in UPDATE 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general, search requests are performed with `GET` method and you don't even need to mention `method="GET"` since it's the default method. Also you don't need the `csrf_token` in your `form` since it's a `GET` request.

If you make those changes, the error should go but you'll get an other error :

```
IntegrityError at /new_search/
NOT NULL constraint failed: my_app_search.search
```

i have no clue, but it seems to be related to your logic with database (sqlite3)

if you share some code i could help you

## Update

in `views.py`

```
def new_search(request):
    # search = request.POST.get('search')
    search = request.GET.get('search')  # the value should be Not NULL and the 'IntegrityError' should go.
```

use `GET` instead `POST` since the search request is performed via `GET` method and you'll get ride off from the `IntegrityError` error. hope this solves your issue.

## Update 2

besides the changes above, i deployed the app on `heroku` with little changes in `settings.py`

```
..
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '.herokuapp.com']  # HERE
..

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# HERE added these lines to override the default database config with postgress settings
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

..
```

and i run this command

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev

heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

that's all what i've already done.

Comment: Oh good to know. I'm still starting my journey so I built this through a tutorial and that's why the GET method was used alongside the csrf_token and for them it worked like this so that's why I'm confused. All the code for the project can be found here https://github.com/MatiasPuletti/craiglist_clone

Comment: @MatíasPuletti i updated my answer. let me know if it works

Comment: I've implemented your suggestion, along with removing the csfr_token but unfortunately, I'm still getting the CSRF token missing or incorrect error. Now, this error is being shown both in Safari and Chrome. I'm clueless. PythonAnywhere support suggested, as you, to remove the token and enable force HTTPS through their dashboard but that's also not working.

Comment: This is what I get now https://dpaste.com/6LFBTNVTH

Comment: it's very strange, i already downloaded your repo, made the changes loclly and it works without any errors on my machine, i guess there's a missing config upon deployment, i'll try to deploy the app on heroku and i'll get back to you, anyway it'll be very first experience with heroku.

Comment: It's strange, isn't it? Also because on my end it still works locally either with GET or POST. I'm waiting for PythonAnywhere's support to get back at me again and I'll stand by to see if with heroku you make it happen. Highly appreciate your willingness to help btw!

Comment: it seems to work (https://my-craiglist-clone.herokuapp.com/) but i get an error related to sqlite3, i'm stuck how to force heroku to create sqlite3 database ? i already used `heroku run python manage.py makemigrations` but it seems no `db.sqlite3` was created if i run this command `heroku run ls- la`

Comment: i'm disappointed because `We can't use the default SQLite database on Heroku because it is file-based`

Comment: Have you tried running the command `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev` to create the database? See step4 here https://medium.com/@qazi/how-to-deploy-a-django-app-to-heroku-in-2018-the-easy-way-48a528d97f9c

Comment: that was tricky with heroku , anyway the app is now working !

Comment: i applied my changes, i guess you didn't removed `method="post"` in your form

Comment: That's great! I only need to remove it and don't specify any GET, right?

Comment: to be sure just inspect the search form of djangoproject.com, this is the wright way to do things

Comment: Just removed it straight from the base.html file in PythonAnywhere, saved it but unfortunately I still get an error.

Comment: did you change `search = request.POST.get('search')` to `search = request.GET.get('search')` in `views.py` ? i already updated my answer

Comment: Yes I've changed that as soon as you updated it. Can't get my get around what's going wrong.

Comment: This is what I get now. https://dpaste.com/2KR82LX3R

Comment: maybe you are missing some thing in  settings.py i'll update my answer